# Menu Collapse in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I have a dynamic menu, and in another question here of Stack I was able to put the class "active" when I clicked on the menu that belongs to his route.
Now, when Tag "a" receives the class "Active" when it is selected.

Good! My problem is: my entire menu is in Collapse mode. How do I start the page by making the "ul" open **according to the selected router**?
Do i have to make a search to find where is the "active" class and from this add "collapse in" to my "ul" parents??

- To open the "ul" menu I have to put the class "collapse in"

Here is my **Menu.vue**:

```
<template>
    <li v-for="item in Menu">
        <router-link :to="{ name: item.Rota }" tag="a" :class="{ 'active': $route.name === item.Rota }">
            {{item.Nome}}
        </router-link>
        <ul class="nav nav-second-level" v-if="item.SubMenu != null">
            <li v-for="SecondItem in item.SubMenu">
                <router-link :to="{ name: SecondItem.Rota }" tag="a" :class="{ 'active': $route.name === SecondItem.Rota }">
                    {{SecondItem.Nome}}
                </router-link>
                <ul class="nav nav-third-level" v-if="SecondItem.MenuItem != null">
                    <li v-for="ThirdItem in SecondItem.MenuItem">
                        <router-link :to="{ name: ThirdItem.Rota }" tag="a" :class="{ 'active': $route.name === ThirdItem.Rota }">
                            {{ThirdItem.Nome}}
                        </router-link>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</template>
<script>
    import axios from 'axios'

    export default {
        data: () => ({
            Menu: []
        }),
        created() {
            let Data = [{
                    "Nome": "Produtos",
                    "MenuItem": [{
                        "Nome": "Catalogos de Produtos",
                        "Rota": "Produtos"
                    }]
                },
                {
                    "Nome": "Menu Teste",
                    "MenuItem": [{
                        "Nome": "Menu Teste Nível 3",
                        "MenuItem": [{
                            "Nome": "Página teste 3",
                            "Rota": "PagTesteTres"
                        }]
                    }]
                }
            ]
            this.Menu = Data;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Can you add a picture showing the problem? Also, why does a `collapse in` class *open* the menu? Normally people talk about "collapsing" a menu to mean *closing* the menu.

Comment: Sure @NathanWailes! Here you are https://imgur.com/a/SgwAf

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand how to interpret that picture; can you explain what's wrong there?

Comment: In this case that's nothing wrong, but if a refresh the page this all menus will close. Did you understand?

Comment: Ok, I think I understand that. Should all of the links shown in your image have the same URL? That doesn't seem right.

Comment: I think it is right. Because there is no URL to menu levels, so it takes the current route

Answer (score 1):

First of all, create your directory paths in router file and get rid of `Data` array.

## router.js

```
  const menuRoutes = [
    {
      path: '/',
      component: MainPage,
      children: [
        path: '/subpage',
        component: Subpage,
        meta: {
          title: 'subpage',
        },
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            name: 'thirdPage',
            component: ShirdPage,
            meta: {
              title: 'Child of subpage',
            },
          },
      ],
    },
  ];
```

## Vue component

```
<template>
    <li v-for="route in MenuRoutes">
        <router-link :to="{ name: item.Rota }" tag="a" :class="{ 'active open': isActiveRoute(route) }">
            {{item.Nome}}
        </router-link>
        <ul class="nav nav-second-level" v-if="item.SubMenu != null">
            <li v-for="route in SubMenuRoutes">
                <router-link :to="{ name: SecondItem.Rota }" tag="a" :class="{ 'active open': isActiveRoute(route) }">
                    {{SecondItem.Nome}}
                </router-link>
                <ul class="nav nav-third-level" v-if="SecondItem.MenuItem != null">
                    <li v-for="route in SubMenuRoutes.children">
                        <router-link :to="{ name: ThirdItem.Rota }" tag="a" :class="{ 'active open':  isActiveRoute(route) }">
                            {{ThirdItem.Nome}}
                        </router-link>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</template>
<script>
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
    computed: {
        menuRoutes() {
            return this.$router.options.routes;
        },
        SubMenuRoutes() {
            return this.$router.options.routes.children;
        }
    },
    methods: {
        isActiveRoute(route) {
            const isActive = this.$route.matched.some(matched => matched.path === route.path);
            return isActive;
        },
    },
}
</script>
```

`isActiveRoute()` method checks if any children of route is actual route so your parent menu will be collapsed when children has been clicked. It depends on `open` class or anything you want to call (for example `collapse open`) so you have to be sure that adding this class to that element in DOM will collapse your menu.

Comment: this answer is good! but i have to put "open" class on "ul". i tryied to do this "isActiveRoute()". but it returns to me "vm_.isActiveRoute is undefined function"